# Rrule generates wrong timeslots when setting specific days and hours in a time range

Tags: java, rrule

I want to get recurring events using Rrule that occurs let's say every Sunday from 3 July until 17 July from 8:00 until 15:00  and lasts 7 hours. So I want the following result:
9 July 08:00 - 15:00
16 July 08:00 - 15:00

How can I achieve this?

I tried the following rule for achieving that:

```
new RRule({
  freq: RRule.HOURLY,
  dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 6, 3, 8, 0, 0)),
  until: new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 6, 17, 15, 0, 0)),
  interval: 7,
  wkst: RRule.SU,
  byweekday: RRule.SU
})

rule.toString():    

DTSTART:20230703T080000Z
RRULE:FREQ=HOURLY;UNTIL=20230717T150000Z;INTERVAL=7;WKST=SU;BYDAY=SU
```

and I got the following:

1   Sun,    09  Jul     2023    04:00:00    GMT
2   Sun,    09  Jul     2023    11:00:00    GMT
3   Sun,    09  Jul     2023    18:00:00    GMT
4   Sun,    16  Jul     2023    04:00:00    GMT
5   Sun,    16  Jul     2023    11:00:00    GMT
6   Sun,    16  Jul     2023    18:00:00    GMT

which is not what I want.